# What's the radical and socle of the path algebra of an infinite acyclic quiver?

Tags: representation-theory, radicals, quiver

Let $Q$ be an infinite quiver without oriented cycle. Is it true that the radical of $KQ$ is generated by all the arrows? Note that we're allowing for infinitely long directed paths. What can we say about its socle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the radical of $KQ$ is the ideal generated by all the arrows, see e.g. [this mathoverflow question and the (more general) reference in the comment](https://mathoverflow.net/a/201698/15887).

To answer the question about the socle observe first that for a module $M$, the submodule $\operatorname{soc}(M)$ is the subspace of all elements $m\in M$ such that all arrows act as zero (otherwise $\operatorname{rad}(A)m$ is a non-zero proper submodule of $M$). In particular, for the path algebra $KQ$, its socle is spanned by all paths ending in sinks.